# Airflow DAG Not following schedule

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that is scheduled once a month.  my problem is that the scheduler is not kicking off the job:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': dates.days_ago(1),
    'email': ['sinistersparrow1701@gmail.com', 'rich@offrs.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
}

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='Offrs_TAX_ASSESSOR_MASTER_Production',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval= '0 0 1 * *',
    catchup=False
)
```

I tried 0 0 1 * *  and I tried @Monthly.  It is not firing.  The DAG works perfectly when executed manually.  Do I have something set wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use dynamic values in `start_date`.

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 4, 1),
    'email': ['sinistersparrow1701@gmail.com', 'rich@offrs.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
}
```

In simple words Airflow calculates `start_date`+`schedule_interval` and execute the task at the end of the interval. When you use dynamic `start_date` you might get a case where the interval never end as the base point is always moving.
This is explained in depth at the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date).